# CSV normalization in Python

Tags: python, normalization

I'm working on a CSV file which contains several medical data and I want to implement it for ML model, but before executing the ML model, I want to normalize the data between 0 to 1. Below is my script, but it's producing error, how to resolve the error

[Sample input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyhD6.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd 
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from pandas import read_csv
Data = ('Medical_Data.csv')
names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class']
dataframe = read_csv(Data, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
# separate array into input and output components
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
# summarize transformed data
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(rescaledX[0:5,:])
```

Error massage: 
could not convert string to float: 'preg'

Comment: Haven't used pandas before, but it seems like you are passing in the data you read before as an argument to `pd.read_csv`, while it expects a file path; see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv

Comment: Plz check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing `pd.read_csv` twice. `Data` will be in a DataFrame format and you cannot perform `pd.read_csv` on a DataFrame.

---- UPDATE

`names` needs to be defined before read_csv. Please refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html .

```py
import pandas as pd 
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from pandas import read_csv
names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class']
dataframe = read_csv('Medical_Data.csv', names=names)
array = dataframe.values
# separate array into input and output components
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
# summarize transformed data
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(rescaledX[0:5,:])
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: same error massage coming , `could not convert string to float: 'preg'` . Please have a look at sample input file

Answer (score 1):

You don`t have to use 'pd.read_csv' twice. Just use like that:

```
names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class']
Data = pd.read_csv('Medical_Data.csv',names=names)
```

and also if you want to get DataFrame's columns, use this code:

```
columns = Data.columns
```

'Data.columns' will return column list

Comment: MinMaxScaler can get only numeric data. preprocess 'preg' column data to numeric